# When a toilet is flushed, clear water drips in basement

Tags: water, toilet

Looking for cause of water dripping. When a toilet is flushed, in our basement below it, clear water drips.  It is clear and not waste water.  After the toilet refills, this stops. It does not happen otherwise.

Comment: Step one, flush some "non-toxic septic dye" to verify that the drip is really clean water, or not.

Comment: Step two, examine the pipe and valve protruding from the wall that fills the toilet for leaks.

Comment: Odd thing is that I dont see any leak from the bathroom wall to the toilet. If that line is under pressure, shouldn't it constantly drip? I can try the  dye idea too.  Puzzling.

Comment: Try flushing dye twice: first time by putting dye in the bowl, second time while putting dye in the tank. It's possible a leak is coming from either place, and this will generate more information as to source than one test.

Comment: If the basement is humid, and the water refilling the tank after a flush is cold, you may have simple condensation on the pipes or toilet tank.

Comment: Condensation does not really fit the "leaks when flushed, stops when refilled" pattern. Condensation takes some time to form to the point of dripping, and then continues to form until the pipe warms up to room temperature.

Comment: Thanks all, investigating more using your ideas ...

Comment: It is not uncommon for a wax ring to leak and by the time the water gets any distance it appears clear most of the water in the system going down is fresh you have 1-2 quarts in the bowl and 3-6 in the tank getting mixed , I have added dye just as the others are suggesting and the home owner could not believe it was from the wax seal failing.

Comment: Divert the output of the fill valve (inside the holding tank) to a bucket.  Open the fill valve manually and see if drips occur.  This lets you distinguish between leaks before and after the fill line.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a broken line that leads to the trap primer of a drain and is meant to fill the drain's trap with a little bit of water every time it's flushed.

This is to prevent the trap drying out and assumes regular toilet use is enough to keep it topped up.

This mechanism should be evident and disable-able or repairable in the top tank or at the join between the tank and the bowl.